# How can I go to specified URL?

Tags: angular, typescript, module, routes

I am creating a routing mechanism on my angular project but I am getting URL routing error. The application can not find the URL.

Here is my routing mechanism.

**navigation.ts**

```
{
        id: 'documentation-management',
        title: 'Dokümantasyon Yönetimi',
        type: 'collapse',
        icon: 'feather icon-folder',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'documentation-list',
            title: 'Doküman Listesi',
            type: 'item',
            url: '/tr/documentation-management/documentation/documentation-list'
          },
          {
            id: 'definitions',
            title: 'Tanımlar',
            type: 'collapse',
            children: [
              {
                id: 'documentation-category',
                title: 'Doküman Kategorileri',
                type: 'item',
                url: '/tr/documentation-management/definitions/documentation-category/documentation-category-list'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
   path: ':lang/documentation-management',
   loadChildren: './documentation-management/documentation-management.module#DocumentationManagementModule'
}
```

**documentation-management-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'documentation',
        loadChildren: './documentation/documentation.module#DocumentationModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'definitions',
        loadChildren: './definitions/definitions.module#DefinitionsModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**definitions-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'documentation-category',
        loadChildren: './documentation-category/documentation-category.module#DocumentationCategoryModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**documentation-category-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'documentation-category-list',
        loadChildren: './documentation-category-list/documentation-category-list.module#DocumentationCategoryListModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'documentation-category-edit',
        loadChildren: './documentation-category-edit/documentation-category-edit.module#DocumentationCategoryEditModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'documentation-category-edit/:id',
        loadChildren: './documentation-category-edit/documentation-category-edit.module#DocumentationCategoryEditModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**documentation-category-list-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DocumentationCategoryListComponent
  }
];
```

I have same routing mechanism for different module and it is working. I do not know this is not working.

I should be able to go to specified URL in **navigation.ts** file, but I am getting below error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tr/documentation-management/definitions/documentation-category/documentation-category-list'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tr/documentation-management/definitions/documentation-category/documentation-category-list'
```

Here is my application structure:

```
- app
  - documentation-management
      - definitions
          - documentation-category
             - documentation-category-list

  - human-resources
      - definitions
          - education-group
             - education-group-list
```

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Try adding one ‘route level’ at a time. There is a lot of routes.

Comment: Yes looks like pretty complicated. What is this => "documentation-category-edit/:id" . I can't     see role of :id

Comment: Problem is about documentation-category-list, not documentation-category-edit. @Nikola Lukic

Comment: I have the same routing with a different route and it is working. @Jens Alenius

Comment: Wondering about the levels. You will have a route like: 'server-url/definitions/documentation-category/documentation-category-list' is it necessary? I would understand it if you had like server-url/definitions/{}/documentation-category/{}/documentation-category-list. But maybe you have?

Comment: I mean. Would it not be enough with server-url/documentation-category-list?

Answer (score 0):

In `app.routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'documentation-management', loadChildren: () => import('./path to the module/documentation-management.module').then(mod => mod.documentationManagement)
}
];
```

In your documentationManagement's routing module import the other modules same as this.

Comment: Why are we using like this? I am asking because of my curiosity.

Comment: In angular 8 its the new way of importing the module. It imports that module when the path is invoked. thus making less memory on browser to make the app faster.(lazy loading feature)

Comment: Don't try with `tr/documentation-management/definitions/documentation-category/documentation-category-list`.
Just use `documentation-category-list`(if your using from the same module)

Comment: Try with 1 level. If that fails, there might be different problem.

Comment: From which module's component your tring to hit routerLink?

Comment: I did with 1 level. I am trying from the dashboard component. But the problem is different I assume. Because when I use the below URL. It is working. 

 `url: '/tr/human-resources/definitions/education-group/education-group-list'`

Comment: I updated my question and added the project structure. The weird thing is here; education-group-list is working but not documentation-category-list. Why?

Comment: Does `definition` is there in both the structures ?

Comment: And also check at the root routing `:lang/documentation-management`. did you add this in your routerLink?

Comment: If this doesn't help. Can you create a stackblitz project and replicate the error there?

Comment: Yes, I have it in both structures.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Angular doesn't allow same module name in it's routing mechanism. It doesn't matter these modules are in different folder structure.

When I change;

```
{
   path: 'definitions',
   loadChildren: './definitions/definitions.module#DefinitionsModule'
}
```

to

```
{
   path: 'definitions',
   loadChildren: './definitions/definitions.module#DocumentationManagementDefinitionsModule'
}
```

It worked.